# Add the related objects of User and display them in User model in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am having two models projects and User in projects the User is related like shown below
models.py:

```
class project(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(room,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ManyToManyField(goal)
    design = models.ManyToManyField(design)
    furniture = models.ForeignKey(furniture,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Now here I want to display the extra column as projects in user page in django admin for every user when I click on that it should take to particular project detail page of that user
Screenshots:
This is the user list page
[image]

This is the project list page
[image]

This is the project detail page 
[image]

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import project
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('user','room','goal','design','furniture','created_at','updated_at')

admin.site.register(project,ProjectAdmin)
```

Please help me out Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write a custom admin for your User:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

UserModel = get_user_model()

admin.site.unregister(UserModel)

@admin.register(UserModel)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_project'
    )

    def user_project(self, obj):
        url = '/admin/modsy/project/{}/change/'.format(obj.project.pk)
        return mark_safe('<a href="{}">view project</a>'.format(url))
```

Comment: AttributeError at /admin/auth/user/
'User' object has no attribute 'project'
Getting this error in user page in admin can you please help

Comment: On your project model add a ``related_name`` to the user field: ``user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)``